# Trato de hacer un reproductor de música sin embargo cuando le doy al botón de play este no hace nada

Tags: java

Estoy empezando a aprender Java y quise hacer un programa que fuera capaz de reproducir musica sin embargo cuando este se ejecuta el boton de play no cumple con su cometido tienen idea de que pueda estar haciendo mal?
no se si sea de ayuda pero programo con visual studio code y me sale que las applet estan obsoletas puede que tenga algo que ver tambien?
trate de implementar todo lo que se me vino a la mente desde eventos con el mouse y demas pero seguia sin funcionar el botón
Este es el codigo, importe todo lo que pense que me podría solucionar el error xd

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.awt.Frame;


public class Musica extends Frame implements ActionListener {
    
  
    
    JFrame f= new JFrame("Reproductor");
    JLabel Lab1;
    JButton b;



    public Musica() {
   
    Lab1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("04_ejercicio_cuatro/Pikachu.png"));
    Lab1.setBounds(200, -100, 800, 800);

    b= new JButton("Play");
    b.setBounds(100,100,150,100);

    f.add(b);
    f.add(Lab1);
    f.setSize(1200, 800);
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    b.addActionListener(this);
    


  
} 

public class rep extends Applet {}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    AudioClip sound;
    sound = java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(getClass().getResource("06_ejercicio_seis/background.wav"));
    sound.play();

}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Musica().setVisible(true);


   } });
         
        
    }
}
```

```
public class Reproductor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Musica reproductor = new Musica();
        reproductor.setVisible(true);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Qué versión de Java estás usando?

Comment: Muchas gracias por la bienvenida tengo la versión 11.0.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muy aparte que se trata de una *API* ya en desuso como lo es *Applet*, he podido reproducir audio teniendo en cuenta un par de cosas:

Una es tener seguro al 100% que la ruta al archivo *.wav* es la correcta.

Otra es que `play()` reproduce el contenido muy brevemente tanto que no se puede oír en su totalidad, por lo que hay que mantener *vivo* ese proceso de reproducción (*un* `sleep()` *puede ayudar*).

Abajo la posible solución:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
  try {
    AudioClip sound;
    sound=Applet.newAudioClip(getClass().getResource("sounds/mySound.wav"));
    sound.play();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Con lo anterior, si aún así no funciona, entonces es muy probable que tu archivo *.wav* no sea un tipo que `AudioClip` pueda reproducir o que necesite alguna especie de *codec* no soportado por la API de Applet.

### Edit:

En efecto, probando con varios *.wav* tuve algunos que no se reprodujeron, en tanto otros que si sin problemas; para tenerlo bastante en cuenta ;)